# Antd TypeScript : Log data when user clicks enter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, antd

In the project I'm working, I have wrapped the input around a form, and the idea is when the user types something and clicks enter, the data is logged. But the issue is I'm not getting such logs.

Here is my code :

Index.tsx

```
const onFinish = (values: any) => {
  console.log("yoyo");
  console.log(values);
};

<Form name="control-ref" onMouseEnter={onFinish}>
        <Form.Item name="note" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
          <InputField
              variant="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              addonAfter={selectAfter}
              className="search-field"
            />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
```

The `InputField` with the specified variant returns this components

```
const SearchField: React.FC<IInputFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const { placeholder } = props;
  return (
    <Input
      className="search-field"
      placeholder={placeholder || 'Search'}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Log the data when the form is submitted. Forms can be submitted by pressing enter.

```
<Form name="control-ref" onFinish={(values: any) => {
    console.log("yoyo");
    console.log(values);
}}>
    {...}
</Form>
```

**Edit:** updated submission callback according to [ant design react docs](https://ant.design/components/form)

Comment: I'm getting this error if I do this though : `Type '{ children: Element; name: string; onSubmit: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ref?: Ref<FormInstance<any>> | undefined; }'.
  Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ref?: Ref<FormInstance<any>> | undefined; }'`

Comment: what library are you using for the `Form` component?

Comment: I'm using Antd library

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm still not getting the logs

Comment: Other triggers are not working either if enter is clicked